# How does including lags imply losing observations

Tags: time-series, arima, augmented-dickey-fuller

[image]

My time series professor passed a comment today, that running this model implies losing k+1 observations. I think I have understood how the observations are wasted, but I am notorious for falsely believing that I have understood something(self-diagnosed). A simple explanation would be appreciated!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Imagine that you have ten periods of observation in your data set:

`period : 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10`
`var_t  : 7 6 7 8 9 4 4 3 6 5`

Imagine that you wish to to include a lag of one period on some variables:

`period : 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10`
`var_t  : 7 6 7 8 9 4 4 3 6 5`
`var_t-1: . 7 6 7 8 9 4 4 3 6`

Notice that you do not have a lagged value for `var_t=1` because you did not observe the value of `var_t` in the period *before* `t=1`, and thus do not know its lagged value.

So with a lag of two:

`period : 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10`
`var_t  : 7 6 7 8 9 4 4 3 6 5`
`var_t-1: . 7 6 7 8 9 4 4 3 6`
`var_t-2: . . 7 6 7 8 9 4 4 3`

So you see, adding additional lags to a fixed number of observations implies a loss of observations (e.g. with lag of two, you have only eight periods of observation for values of `period`, `var_t`, `var_t-1` *and* `var_t-2`).

Comment: ahh!, my initial idea of it was very vague but something along these lines. this example cleared it up nicely, thank you!