# Can I incorporate differencing into a (Cox) survival model?

Tags: regression, survival, cox-model, time-varying-covariate

I am predicting college student dropout with a Cox model. I believe that a declining grade point average (GPA) is predictive of dropout, and I want to incorporate this into my model. I'm looking for something analogous to differencing in time series, where you create a new observation,

$$y_t^{\prime} = y_{t} - y_{t-1} \ ,$$

from the previous observations. Higher order differencing like $y^{\prime \prime} = y^{\prime}_t - y^{\prime}_{t-1}$ may be helpful, but I do not know if it adds extra complications.

Survival analysis is not my area of expertise, but I am familiar with many of the simpler methods, so references to good papers on the topic are appreciated.

Toy data:

```
# Generate data --------------------------------------
student = rep(1:3, each = 3)
semester = rep(1:3, times = 3)
GPA = c(4,3,2, 3.5, 4.0, 3.7, 2.1, 0, 3.1)
dat = data.frame(student, semester, GPA)

# Create lag -------------------------------
library("dplyr")
dat %>% 
  group_by(student) %>% 
   mutate(GPA.diff = GPA - lag(GPA, n = 1))
```

I would like to use that new variable, GPA.diff, in my Cox regression as a time varying predictor.

Comment: What is hindering you from using the "_new variable, `GPA.diff`, in my cox regression as a time varying predictor._"?

Comment: Nothing. I’m unsure if that’s the correct method. You’d lose 1/3 of the data in the above example?

Comment: That depends on your definition of time zero.

Comment: You might want to see [my answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/97225/how-does-including-lags-imply-losing-observations/97226#97226) to the question [How does including lags imply losing observations?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/97225/how-does-including-lags-imply-losing-observations).